# Show text if no result (but only once)

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

Thanks to some help I have a working php file. I'm tweaking it at the moment so it will give me a certain text when there is no data found in a database..

The problem is, I think I got the logic, just don't know the code for it. Let me start with showing the code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '**********';
$dbpass = '**********';
$database = '**********';
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if (isset($_GET['zoeknummer']))  {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$database", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $sql = "SELECT lead_content
    FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads";
        $res = $pdo->query($sql);     // where $pdo is your db connection

    while  ($lead = $res->fetchColumn()) {

        $data = json_decode($lead);

    if ($data->zoeknummer == $_GET['zoeknummer']) {
        echo "Uw plaats voor " ; 
        echo $data->wachtlijstkomplex . ' : ' . $data->wachtlijstplaats . '<br>';
        }     
    else {
        echo 'Geen resultaat gevonden met opgegeven nummer. <br> Kijk na of U het nummer correct heeft ingevuld.';
        }
    }
}?>
```

I understand that the 'while' makes it search the whole database and the if will show the result found.

I also understand that the else will show the text when there is no data found in that column, and I understand it will do that for each column no data is found, and there is the problem.

I only want it to show the text displaying once. No mather how many columns it has searched in. This code now also shows text for all espty searches and will show the result in between all the negative results.

The logic I get is that i need to get the 'else' out the 'while' but that's it. Any help would be appreciated, i'm still trying to understand this php language and am learning, I know the solution might be as simple as breaking an egg.. but if you don't know what an egg is.. ;-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indeed, breaking something is part of the solution, though not an egg but [breaking a loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) :) Read it and [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) reading here.

Comment: You should not get all rows from your database and loop through them to find a certain number. Instead add a `WHERE` clause to your query and only get the row you need, if any.

Comment: Hi Alon_A.

I understand 'logical' what you mean here. But wouldn't this 'break' the loop as soon as it finds a result? There can be more results for 1 query, and the database doesn't have a fixed size, so it should read all the rules and 'echo' eacht result that has a hit, but if there aren't any at all, then i want a other text to be seen.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, that's why I've only posted a comment. yes, `break` will get out from the loop and `continue` will continue to the next iteration. These are important basic operators that should be learned and that's the second reason for posting them in my comment.

Comment: Hey jeroen

i think there was a problem with my database to work this way. The result should be filtered from the whole line in that database that looks simular to this: "field1, field2, field3, field4" and the search should see if the give data is equal to the data in field2 and then echo field3 & field4

As said before, my knowledge to php can be seen and 0 i worked over 2 day's on this little code and had help from different places to finally get it to work. I understand the logic, i just don't know the attributes

Comment: Hey Alon_A, maybe i didn't explain it very clear, thanks again for having a look with me ;-) i was thinking the same way tbh, but where after the loop i would only 'echo' "no results" or something simular, but only if there was no result at all. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help, it's working now, i shall post the result code so it's helpfull for people with the same problem:

```
if (isset($_GET['zoeknummer']))  
                                {   
                                    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$database", $dbuser, $dbpass);
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                                    $sql = "SELECT lead_content
                                        FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads";
                                    $res = $pdo->query($sql);     // where $pdo is your db connection
                                    $flag=false;

                                    while  ($lead = $res->fetchColumn()) 
                                    {               
                                        $data = json_decode($lead);
                                        if ($data->zoeknummer == $_GET['zoeknummer']) 
                                        {
                                            echo "Uw plaats voor " ; 
                                            echo $data->wachtlijstkomplex . ' : ' . $data->wachtlijstplaats . '<br>';
                                            $flag=true;
                                        }

                                    }

                                    if ($flag==false)
                                    {
                                        echo 'Geen resultaat gevonden met opgegeven nummer. <br> Kijk na of U het nummer correct heeft ingevuld.';
                                    }

                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = '**********';
    $dbpass = '**********';
    $database = '**********';
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if (isset($_GET['zoeknummer']))  {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$database", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $sql = "SELECT lead_content FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads";
        $res = $pdo->query($sql);     // where $pdo is your db connection
        $foundResult = false;


    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)               // <------ here
    {
         while  ($lead = $res->fetchColumn()) {

                $data = json_decode($lead);

            if ($data->zoeknummer == $_GET['zoeknummer']) {
                echo "Uw plaats voor " ; 
                echo $data->wachtlijstkomplex . ' : ' . $data->wachtlijstplaats . '<br>';
                }     
    } else {
           echo 'Geen resultaat gevonden met opgegeven nummer. <br> Kijk na of U het nummer correct heeft ingevuld.';
    }
```

Comment: you mean i should replace 
<code>(isset($_GET['zoeknummer']))  {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$database", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      .....</code>

with <code>if ($res)</code> ?

Comment: No need to use $foundResult = false;

Comment: Hi @DirkJoris. One clear way is to use mysqli_num_rows($result) to check if the result is not empty. I've updated the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks, it seems the code is indeed still a work in progress. It's good to keep getting information so i can keep learning from it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just working of of the code that you do have, I would just set a flag to indicate whether or not you actually found a result in the while loop. Something like this:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = '**********';
    $dbpass = '**********';
    $database = '**********';
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    if (isset($_GET['zoeknummer']))  {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$database", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $sql = "SELECT lead_content FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads";
        $res = $pdo->query($sql);     // where $pdo is your db connection
        $foundResult = false;

        while  ($lead = $res->fetchColumn()) {

            $data = json_decode($lead);

            if ($data->zoeknummer == $_GET['zoeknummer']) {
                echo "Uw plaats voor " ; 
                echo $data->wachtlijstkomplex . ' : ' . $data->wachtlijstplaats . '<br>';
                $foundResult = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$foundResult) {
            echo 'Geen resultaat gevonden met opgegeven nummer. <br> Kijk na of U het nummer correct heeft ingevuld.';
        }
    }?>
```

Comment: Hey there, i tried this, it keeps showing more then 1 (not found) message.